# How do you understand displaced vertices rigorously in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles, particle-detectors

When you produce a long-lived particle (like charged pions, muons), it enters your detector. When you produce a short-lived particle (like the higgs, tau), the production of the particle is only seen as an increase of a certain process when the collision's center of mass energy is near the particle's mass. But there are also medium-lifetime particles (lifetime ~1ns), where they never get anywhere near the detector, but the detector's resolution allows us to identify that the decay products of the particle didn't come from the collision point, but rather a small distance away from the collision point.

I'll keep it simple and try to deal with a theory with just two scalar fields - a lighter one and a heavier one. A tree level diagram involved in calculating the scattering of two lighter particles is this:

[image]

Obviously, the scattering will increase when the center of mass collision energy approaches the mass of the heavy particle, because the propagator's denominator will go to zero. But another phenomenon that we expect to happen near resonance is displaced vertices. The typical description of this process goes something like this: "as the center of mass energy of the 2x light particle collision approaches the heavy particle's mass, you start to produce the on-shell heavy particle. It flies some distance, then decays, giving you a displaced vertex."

This all seems a bit handwavy to me, and I'd like to get a more rigorous understanding of the process. Is there some genuine way to calculate the cross section for displaced vertices of a certain distance? Or do Feynman diagrams for some reason only describe processes that happen in one point in space? How do we properly understand the transition from

1. one Feynman diagram (far off resonance) involved in calculating the cross section for the light particles scattering off one another, mediated by an exchange of a virtual heavy particle
2. to one Feynman diagram used to calculate the cross section for producing a short lived particle that decays (as described by another, separate Feynman diagram)?

Comment: Your are misunderstanding what Feynman diagrams are about. I suggest you pick up an introduction to quantum field theory.

Comment: I don't think I am. What exactly in this question betrays a misunderstanding of Feynman diagrams, and what description of Feynman diagrams resolves this question? Just saying "read an entire 1000 page book" (I already have read what I believe are the relevant parts) isn't really helpful, and isn't really in the spirit of this website.

Comment: Feynman diagrams are a visual representation of different terms in a perturbation expansion, i.e. they are a mathematical concept. Speaking of displaced vertices and distance does not make sense.

Comment: What you're saying seems to just reiterate that my confusion is valid. The heart of my question is - since Feynman diagrams don't seem to be capable of describing a displaced vertex, but displaced vertices are a real and observable phenomenon in accelerators that should in principle be described by quantum field theory, how _do_ we calculate the probability of an observed displaced vertex. And how do we understand the transition from "two light particles scattering by the exchange of a virtual heavy particle" to "the heavy particle is produced, and decays some distance away from the beam pipe"

Comment: In fairness to your criticism, I've edited the phrasing around Feynman diagrams. As a shorthand, I was referring to them more as "things that happen" than as "terms in a sum"

Comment: Or do Feynman diagrams for some reason only describe processes that happen in one point in space? -- They do not account for position in any way., neither if ithe interaction happens in a point or in (almost) all of space-time. Feynman-Diagrams are used to perturbatively calculate the overlap between asymptotic states.

Comment: Well, if you have creation of a Higgs-boson by a $\gamma\gamma$ process which later decays in a bottom-quark pair for instance one has a "creation vertex" and a "decay vertex". Both will have different Feynman diagrams attributed which will have little in common. If you like the decay of the Higgs is a "displaced" vertex but for a Higgs the displacement would be very very small. So if there is a displacement we can assume that the created particle ($H^0$) is on-shell.

Comment: I'd suggest to research on: Pole approximation and the Complex Mass Scheme

Comment: @FredericThomas this seems like just a reiteration of the "handwavy explanation" that's already included in my question. Note also that the created higgs is not "on shell exactly" but rather within 1/lifetime of being on-shell. I'm looking for a more rigorous explanation of how we transition from off-shell virtual particles to on-shell particles that actually traverse some distance. Note also that the higgs production can be perfectly well calculated in one diagram, where $d\bar{d}\rightarrow H^0\rightarrow t\bar{t}\rightarrow \gamma$ (top quark loop)

Comment: If they traverse a distance they can only do it on mass shell, i,e. their  four vector should be on mass shell. By definition of the mathematics of Feynman diagrams virtual particles are off mass shell .

Comment: I can take another example: pion decay in a myon in the stratosphere and final decay of the myon in a electron +2neutrinos on earth's ground. 2 processes so with one "displaced vertex". In practical work we detected the arrival of the myons (still not decayed) on the ground. Surely they were on-shell. Of course you can also calculate a diagram with the 2 processes included, I am not an expert of it, so you should follow the hint of @AlmostClueless on "Pole approximation and the Complex Mass Scheme" to know more. But generally there is smooth transition between "almost on-shell" and on-shell"

Comment: @FredericThomas in your example there is an incoherent sum of feynman diagram calculations

Comment: This is definitely an interesting question, which I haven't seen addressed in textbooks. It should be possible to explain it in terms of diagrams, but not naturally -- the usual Feynman diagram rules give you momentum-space scattering amplitudes, but a displaced vertex is a position-space quantity. They're related essentially by Fourier transform, so the information is in there somewhere, but encoded in a weird way that probably has to do with how the phase of the momentum-space scattering amplitude varies near the resonance. I hope somebody gives a good answer here!

Comment: @knzhou thanks for the support - I totally agree - in most of the typical calculations done in QFT, we have removed our ability to work with the position-space, and to answer this one would have to start pretty early on in the derivation of scattering amplitudes and somehow retain that position-space part of the algebra. My only additional realization since I wrote this question is that there might be a mott-problem-related aspect to why  we observe particles as decaying at a particular point in space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem